# Is $\|u v\|_{L^2} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^\infty}\|v\|_{L^2}$ true because of Holder's inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue integrable function on a measure space  $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$, then we may have 
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{L^1} &:= \int_S |f| d\mu \\
\|f\|_{L^2} &:= \left(\int_S |f|^2 d\mu\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
\|f\|_{L^\infty} &:= \inf\{C\ge0: |f|\le C \quad \text{a.e.-}\mu \}
\end{align}

Is there any inequality like 
\begin{align}
\|f\|_{L^1} \le 
\|f\|_{L^2} \le
\|f\|_{L^\infty}
\end{align}
And why?

I am asking because I saw an inequality in some handout that
\begin{align}
|(uv,w)_{L^2}| \lesssim \|u\|_{L^\infty}\|v\|_{L^2}\|w\|_{L^2}
\end{align}
I know the first step the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is applied so 
\begin{align}
|(uv,w)_{L^2}| \lesssim \|u v\|_{L^2}\|w\|_{L^2}
\end{align}
but I don't understand why there holds
\begin{align}
\|u v\|_{L^2}\|w\|_{L^2} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^\infty}\|v\|_{L^2}\|w\|_{L^2}
\end{align}

In particular, why does there hold
\begin{align}
\|u v\|_{L^2} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^\infty}\|v\|_{L^2}
\end{align}

It looks like Holder's inequality applied but the $p,q$ do not satisfy conjugates. Can you show me how to use Holder's inequality to derive this inequality?

Comment: If $u\leq M$ a.s. then $\sqrt{    \int u^2v^2 } \leq  \sqrt{    \int M^2v^2 } =M \sqrt{    \int v^2 } $

Comment: Thank you for your simple and clear answer! But I still want to know if we can, perhaps, derive this from Holder's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Holder's inequality for $q=1$ and $p=\infty$ i.e.

\begin{align*}
\|v u\|_2 &=\sqrt{\|v^2 u^2 \|_1}\\
&\leq    \sqrt{\| v^2\|_\infty}\sqrt{ \| u^2\|_1}\\
&=\|v\|_\infty \|u\|_2
\end{align*}
And for the proof someone can see Martin's answer.

In certain cases the previous version of Holder's can be, easily, derived from the more popular one, i.e. when $1<p,q<\infty$. 
Indeeed, 
$$ \int v^2 u^2 dx \leq \sqrt[p]{\int v^{2p}}  \sqrt[q]{\int u^{2q}}   $$

For $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$.
When $ q\longrightarrow 1$ then $p\longrightarrow \infty$.

Someone can argue, in certain cases, that $\sqrt[p]{\int v^{2p}}\longrightarrow \| u\|^2 _\infty$.

Again, under certain conditions, it can be shown that $\int u^{2q} \rightarrow \int u^2  $.

Comment: Any written criticism, would be welcome:), as I am not sure what is wrong with the post.

Comment: I am not really sure, but I believe that for Hölder's inequality to hold, the requirement between exponents is that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$, and in you case $p=2, q=\infty$ it don´t fullfill it. Also about the inequalities for individual norms, I make the same question recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278551/it-is-always-true-that-ft-1-geq-ft-2-geq-ft-infty-for-int)

Answer (score 4):

It's not Hölder. You have 
$$
\|uv\|_2^2=\int |uv|^2=\int |u|^2\,|v|^2\leq\|u\|_\infty^2\,\int |v|^2=\|u\|_\infty\,\|v\|_2^2. 
$$
It's just that $|u|\leq\|u\|_\infty$ a.e.