# Does Hölder's Inequality implies that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t) \,g(t)|\,\mathrm dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|\,\mathrm dt \, \sup |g|$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces, integral-inequality, holder-inequality

Does Hölder's Inequality implies that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t) \,g(t)|\,\mathrm dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)|\,\mathrm dt \sup_t |g(t)|$ ?

I am thinking in the case $p=1$ and $q=\infty$ so $1=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}$ holds, but I am not sure if the norms $||\cdot||_\infty$ and $||\cdot||_1$ are well interpreted from what it is said on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm), and also if the inequality is valid on unbounded domains as $(-\infty;\,\infty)$.

Also please this related question I had left [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278551/it-is-always-true-that-ft-1-geq-ft-2-geq-ft-infty-for-int). Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it works ... and the proof is quite immediate: just notice that $|f(t)\,g(t)|≤ (\sup_s{|g(s)|})\ |f(t)|$, and now since $\sup_s{|g(s)|}$ is just a constant independent of $t$, you can put it out of the integral ...

Comment: Is not clear for me since they are under a integral and $g(t)$ could be of the form $e^{-iwt}$ so $|e^{-iwt}|=1$, and then a sum of complex modulated values will have magnitude always less than the sum of the unmodulated values magnitudes, ¿is that right?

Comment: I do not understand your problem but let me add details then ... $C = \sup |g|$ is real. So since $|f(t)g(t)|≤ |f(t)|\,|g(t)| ≤ C\, |f(t)|$, we deduce
$$
∫ |f(t) g(t)|\,\mathrm d t \leq ∫ C |f(t)|\,\mathrm d t = C ∫ |f(t)|\,\mathrm d t
$$
At which step do you have a difficulty here?